# intranet bottle pages cannot be reached

Tags: python, server, localhost, bottle, intranet

In my macbook;
the static pages in my bottle server serving at port 8090 can be reached in the localhost but cannot reached at my intranet-IP.
On the other hand, the httpd server serving at port 8080 can be reached at both interfaces:localhost and intranet-ip

Any suggestions to solve bottle lack of connectivity at my intranet-IP? Thanks!

Comment: Your bottle is probably listening only on the localhost interface. While httpd is listening on more interfaces (probably 0.0.0.0). Make your bottle server listen on the external interface (or all interfaces)

Comment: Yes, that was the case